# Need help mounting hard disks

Tags: mount

I get this after running fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         522     4192933+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2             523       60540   482094585   83  Linux
/dev/sda3           60541       60801     2096482+  82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2              14       60801   488279610   8e  Linux LVM
```

and my df -h

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             446G  397G   27G  94% /
/dev/sda1             3.9G   84M  3.6G   3% /boot
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

Can I get step-by-step instructions for mounting this hard disk? I tried search online but everything seems to be different from what I have. Also, what directory should I mount to if I want the files to be accessible by apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2              14       60801   488279610   8e  Linux LVM
```

As I understand, you want to mount the `/dev/sdb2`. Pay attention to the `Id` and `System` columns, it shows `8e` and `LVM` volume. You cannot mount it in the same way as you did with standard partition (ext3, ext4, ...)

List all physical volumes with:

```
# pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  VolGroup00 lvm2 a-   931.41G    0 
  /dev/sdb2  VolGroup00 lvm2 a-   931.50G    0
```

Next, list the logical volumes in `VolGroup00`:

```
# lvdisplay /dev/VolGroup00
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
  VG Name                VolGroup00
  LV UUID                Eq8ceD-6A07-lfTw-QHoB-l8Hj-Rz0l-Ijsoro
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.81 TB
  Current LE             59175
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01
  VG Name                VolGroup00
  LV UUID                pQG1xT-0PTT-xn35-QdVd-67Di-zYmr-xkb3WK
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                13.69 GB
  Current LE             438
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

Take a look at the `LV Size` and mount the logical volume you want:

```
mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/data
```

To make Apache can write to this folder:

```
chown -R apache:apache /mnt/data
```

---

If there is no existing data, and you want to format it as a 'normal' partition, do it with:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
```

and follow the prompt.

Create an ext3 filesystem:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
```

Mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/data
```

Comment: Why does my pvs command display nothing?

Comment: Also does sdb1 need to be mounted

Comment: Could you please run `lvm vgchange -ay` and try again. About the `/dev/sdb1`, take notice of `Boot` column, it used to be a `/boot` partition. So, you don't need to mount it. Do you takeover this server from previous Sysadmin?

Comment: My friend who was helping me called mkfs.ext3 on sdb1 and sdb2 and then mount on both. How can I backtrack and do what you taught me? I have no experience with sysadmin and this is my first server

Comment: Do you want to keep existing data if it has?

Comment: No existing data

Comment: Please check out my above answer.

Comment: Is there a good way to verify that this worked correctly? I see the drive in df -h

Comment: If you saw in `df -h`, it means that it is already mounted.